# All columns of table should be indexed or not mysql database?

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, search-engine

I want to make one table with 4 columns. One is the primary key and the other three columns are references to columns of other tables. I want to use it to join these four tables to make a search filter. These joins are taking time.

I was thinking I should index these columns because I read that adding indexes on column used in join conditions [makes them run faster]. My question is will there be a problem if all columns of the table are indexed? Or is there any other way to decrease time complexity of the search filter. Thanks in advance.

More Hint:
Table1(main search)-1000 entries
primary_key
fk1
fk2
fk3

Table2-800 entries
pk1
..(8-9 columns)

Table3-700 entries
pk2
..(10-12 columns)

Table2-850 entries
pk3
..(7-8 columns)

Comment: What engine your tables are using? Do you use foreign keys?

Comment: @piotrekkr: I am using MyISAM engine. And no foreign keys are there. All 3 other tables have thousands of data and it will grow by day.

Comment: why not just index the columns that you are currently joining on? So say `t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id` then make sure you have an index on t1.id and an index on t2.id. I don't really see a need for a separate table for this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Creating an index requires additional disk space, and that too many indexes can cause issues arising from the file systems size limits, careful thought must be used to select the correct fields to index.

Since indexes are only used to speed up the searching for a matching field within the records, it stands to reason that indexing fields used only for output would be simply a waste of disk space and processing time when doing an insert or delete operation, and thus should be avoided. Also given the nature of a binary search, the cardinality or uniqueness of the data is important. Indexing on a field with a cardinality of 2 would split the data in half, whereas a cardinality of 1,000 would return approximately 1,000 records. With such a low cardinality the effectiveness is reduced to a linear sort, and the query optimizer will avoid using the index if the cardinality is greater than 30% of the record number, effectively making the index a waste of space.

So better to add indexing on group of columns.

Answer (score 5):

To properly index your data for performance, you need to understand your data. Hypothetically, say I was creating a census database table:

```
CREATE TABLE CENSUS
(
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    GENDER CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    FAVOURITEFOOD NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    STATE NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
```

Because of working the data, I may know that:

- Gender is split 50% male, 50% female
- 60% loves roast, 20% are vegetarian, 20% likes asian food, 20% likes pasta
- State is 25% Californian, 25% New York, and the remainder 1% per state.

If I wanted to search for Male people who like roasts and live in California, I would consider making multi column index putting STATE first (STATE, GENDER, FAVOURITEFOOD). I make FAVOURITEFOOD the last column in the index. This is because the STATE filter will chop the data by 25% whereas the FAVOURITEFOOD will return back a majority of the database (no better than a full table scan).

If I wanted to search for Female people who like vegetarian food and live in New York, I would consider making a multi column index and putting FAVOURITEFOOD first (FAVOURITEFOOD, STATE, GENDER). Here, FAVOURITEFOOD chops the data by 20% so it's a much better choice over the other two columns.

If I run BOTH queries often, which index should I make? The answer is both:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_CENSUS_001 ON CENSUS (STATE, GENDER, FAVOURITEFOOD);
CREATE INDEX IX_CENSUS_002 ON CENSUS (FAVOURITEFOOD, STATE, GENDER);
ANALYZE TABLE CENSUS;
```

The [ANALYZE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/analyze-table.html) command stores the key distribution for the table. Now, when you run either query, it will determine whether IX_CENSUS_001 or IX_CENSUS_002 is the best index for the execution plan.

If, I wish to start running different types of queries, I will stop and think about my data again. I may need to add a new index and I may need to run ANALYZE TABLE again.

So, coming back to your scenario; it depends on the data you have in your tables and the queries you wish to perform on it.

Answer (score 3):

Indexes are not magic pills.

Sure, they can speed up queries, but they also slow down writes (inserts/updates/deletes) and take up precious RAM.

Use them carefully.

Comment: Indeed, it's impossible to say which columns should be indexed *and in what copmbinations* without knowing a lot more about the size of the tables they reference, the cardinality and relationships between the tables.

Answer (score 3):

IN the referencing table columns, there must be an index where the foreign key columns are listed as the first columns in the same order.

Such an index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not exist.

Go through below article to understand batter : [How To Index For Joins With MySQL](http://hackmysql.com/case4)

Comment: The reference provides a good explanation. Though it is outdated and no longer supported, it is informative and can be useful.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL allows several types of indexes like primary key index, unique index, normal index also known as ("non-unique index", ordinary index, index without constraints") and full-text index. Of course, the indexes improve SELECT queries speed tremendously. but, they do have some considerable disadvantages as well.
Advantages of MySQL Indexes

Generally speaking, MySQL indexing into database gives you three advantages:

```
Query optimization: Indexes make search queries much faster.
Uniqueness: Indexes like primary key index and unique index help to avoid duplicate row data.
Text searching: Full-text indexes in MySQL version 3.23.23, users have the opportunity to optimize searching against even large amounts of text located in any field indexed as such.
```

[check out this](http://blog.bounceweb.com/importance-of-proper-indexing-for-better-searching-in-your-database/)

Answer (score 1):

Adding an index to a column means that the database has to do more work on every write, but can save time on some reads.

If your queries are taking a long time adding a covering index for joins can help speed things up a lot, but as with all optimisation work, make sure that you have suitable metrics to compare with both before and after the 'optimisation'!

However, since you are joining on a table per column, there will be no need for the indexes since you already have the primary key and a full row read is necessary anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think that indexing all four columns will not really improve your performance because you'll still need a full index scan which will essentially end up the same as a full table scan. Your index will just be a repeat of the data in your table. Can you paste your query?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding indexes if you add the primary key of the main table to the other tables and join the tables on this field would be faster.